# Advent of code 2023 day 3: count engine part numbers - in pure Bash

Tags: programming-challenge, bash

Yes I'll keep [doing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288198/advent-of-code-2023-day-2-in-pure-bash) [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288183/advent-of-code-2023-day-1-mostly-in-bash) until I cannot be bothered to do it in Bash ;-) (Well today is probably the last one ;-))

#### Part 1

To paraphrase the [puzzle](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/3), given some input ("engine schematic") like this:

> ```
> 467..114..
> ...*......
> ..35..633.
> ......#...
> 617*......
> .....+.58.
> ..592.....
> ......755.
> ...$.*....
> .664.598..
> ```

The task is to compute the sum of integers that are adjacent to a non-digit horizontally, vertically, or diagonally. In the above example, only 114 and 58 are not adjacent to any symbol.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Solver for https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/3 part 1
# Redirect the input file to this script, for example day3part1.sh < path/to/input.txt
#

set -euo pipefail

solve_2023_day3_part1() {
  local lines first_line sum i j line num segment_current segment_next segment_prev

  # Read lines, padded with '.' characters at top, bottom, left, right.
  lines=()
  read -r first_line
  lines+=(".${first_line//?/.}.")
  lines+=(".$first_line.")

  while read -r line; do
    lines+=(".$line.")
  done
  lines+=(".${first_line//?/.}.")

  sum=0

  # For each row index except the padding row before and after.
  for ((i = 1; i < ${#lines[@]} - 1; ++i)); do
    line=${lines[i]}

    # For each column index except the padding column at the start and end.
    for ((j = 1; j < ${#line} - 1; )); do
      # Try to match numeric prefix.
      if [[ ${line:j} =~ ^([0-9]+) ]]; then
        num=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        # Check if the line segment on the current line, or above or below
        # has any non-numeric non-dot value.
        ((segment_length = ${#num} + 2))
        segment_current=${line:j-1:segment_length}
        segment_prev=${lines[i-1]:j-1:segment_length}
        segment_next=${lines[i+1]:j-1:segment_length}
        if [[ "$segment_current$segment_prev$segment_next" =~ [^.0-9] ]]; then
          ((sum += num))
        fi

        ((j += ${#num} + 1))
      else
        ((++j))
      fi
    done
  done

  echo "$sum"
}

solve_2023_day3_part1
```

#### Part 2

To paraphrase the change in part 2, we're looking for `*` symbols ("gears") that are adjacent to precisely two integers, and compute the sum of the product of adjacent integers. In the above example this would be 467 * 35 + 755 * 598 = 16345 + 451490 = 467835.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Solver for https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/3 part 2
# Redirect the input file to this script, for example day3part2.sh < path/to/input.txt
#

set -euo pipefail

solve_2023_day3_part2() {
  local lines first_line gears_to_parts line
  local num offset row col i j separator
  local sum value g1 g2 rest

  # Read lines, padded with '.' characters at top, bottom, left, right.
  lines=()
  read -r first_line
  lines+=(".${first_line//?/.}.")
  lines+=(".$first_line.")

  while read -r line; do
    lines+=(".$line.")
  done
  lines+=(".${first_line//?/.}.")

  # Mapping of gear positions and list of adjacent numbers.
  declare -A gears_to_parts
  separator=' '

  # For each row index except the padding row before and after.
  for ((i = 1; i < ${#lines[@]} - 1; ++i)); do
    line=${lines[i]}

    # For each column index except the padding column at the start and end.
    for ((j = 1; j < ${#line} - 1; )); do
      # Try to match numeric prefix.
      if [[ ${line:j} =~ ^([0-9]+) ]]; then
        num=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        # Find all "gears" around the number.
        for offset in -1 0 1; do
          ((row = i + offset)) || true
          for ((col = j-1; col < j + ${#num} + 1; ++col)); do
            if [ "${lines[row]:col:1}" = '*' ]; then
              # Gear found, add current number to list of numbers
              # next to this gear position.
              gears_to_parts[$row:$col]+="$num$separator"
            fi
          done
        done

        ((j += ${#num} + 1))
      else
        ((++j))
      fi
    done
  done

  sum=0
  for value in "${gears_to_parts[@]}"; do
    IFS="$separator" read g1 g2 rest <<< "$value"
    [ "$g2" ] && ! [ "$rest" ] && ((sum += g1 * g2))
  done
  echo "$sum"
}

solve_2023_day3_part2
```

#### Review request

I do realize this is a bit whimsical, and Bash is a poor choice to solve algorithmic puzzles. Also, this code is intended as a one-off, and not for reuse. I'm solving in Bash because, and as long as, it gives me joy. I won't make promises about how far I'm willing to stick to pure Bash, it will depend on the day and my mood. The main principles I do intend to stick to are:

- The program must produce the correct solution to the full input within seconds.
- The program must use idiomatic Bash.

Do you see any patterns here that you would replace with better patterns?

Do you see a simpler way to solve any part of the puzzle with Bash and common shell tools?

What would you do differently?