# Advent of code 2023 day 4: Count scratchcard points - mostly in Bash

Tags: programming-challenge, bash

[Yesterday](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288223/12390) I thought was the last day of Advent Of Code 2023 that I do in Bash. I was wrong. I'm not even sure anymore that today will be the one. We'll just have to see tomorrow!

#### Part 1

To paraphrase the [puzzle](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/4), given some input ("scratchcards") like this:

> ```
> Card 1: 41 48 83 86 17 | 83 86  6 31 17  9 48 53
> Card 2: 13 32 20 16 61 | 61 30 68 82 17 32 24 19
> Card 3:  1 21 53 59 44 | 69 82 63 72 16 21 14  1
> Card 4: 41 92 73 84 69 | 59 84 76 51 58  5 54 83
> Card 5: 87 83 26 28 32 | 88 30 70 12 93 22 82 36
> Card 6: 31 18 13 56 72 | 74 77 10 23 35 67 36 11
> ```

The task is:

1. For each line, count the numbers on the right side that match numbers on the left side. These "winning numbers".
2. Compute the sum of \$2^{count}\$.

That is, in the above example:

- Card 1 has 4 winning numbers -- \$2^3\$ = 8
- Card 2 has 2 winning numbers -- \$2^1\$ = 2
- And so on...

The sum becomes 8 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 13.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Solver for https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/4 part 1
# Redirect the input file to this script, for example day4part1.sh < path/to/input.txt
#

set -euo pipefail

nums_to_lines() {
  local nums oldIFS
  nums=$1

  # Convert the space delimited values to an array.
  # Note: excess spaces are simply ignored.
  nums=($nums)

  # Print array values using newline as delimiter.
  oldIFS=$IFS
  IFS=$'\n'
  echo "${nums[*]}"
  IFS=$oldIFS
}

solve_2023_day4_part1() {
  local left right count sum

  sum=0
  # Read the left and right parts, delimited by '|' 
  while IFS='|' read left right; do
    # Strip the "Card N:" prefix from left.
    left=${left#*: }

    # Count the exact matches of numbers in the right among in the left.
    # Warning: running a program (grep) in a loop is inefficient.
    # When this becomes a performance bottleneck, this is easy enough
    # to implement in pure Bash.
    count=$(grep -xFcf <(nums_to_lines "$right") <(nums_to_lines "$left")) || continue

    # Compute power of 2 and add to sum.
    ((sum += 1 << (count - 1)))
  done

  echo "$sum"
}

solve_2023_day4_part1
```

#### Part 2

To paraphrase the change in part 2... no that would be too hard to paraphrase! So here's the description verbatim!

> Copies of scratchcards are scored like normal scratchcards and have
> the same card number as the card they copied. So, if you win a copy of
> card 10 and it has 5 matching numbers, it would then win a copy of the
> same cards that the original card 10 won: cards 11, 12, 13, 14, and
> 15. This process repeats until none of the copies cause you to win any more cards. (Cards will never make you copy a card past the end of the
> table.)
>
> This time, the above example goes differently:
>
> ```
> Card 1: 41 48 83 86 17 | 83 86  6 31 17  9 48 53
> Card 2: 13 32 20 16 61 | 61 30 68 82 17 32 24 19
> Card 3:  1 21 53 59 44 | 69 82 63 72 16 21 14  1
> Card 4: 41 92 73 84 69 | 59 84 76 51 58  5 54 83
> Card 5: 87 83 26 28 32 | 88 30 70 12 93 22 82 36
> Card 6: 31 18 13 56 72 | 74 77 10 23 35 67 36 11
> ```
>
> - Card 1 has four matching numbers, so you win one copy each of the next four cards: cards 2, 3, 4, and 5.
> - Your original card 2 has two matching numbers, so you win one copy each of cards 3 and 4.
> - Your copy of card 2 also wins one copy each of cards 3 and 4.
> - Your four instances of card 3 (one original and three copies) have two matching numbers, so you win four copies each of cards 4 and 5.
> - Your eight instances of card 4 (one original and seven copies) have one matching number, so you win eight copies of card 5.
> - Your fourteen instances of card 5 (one original and thirteen copies) have no matching numbers and win no more cards.
> - Your one instance of card 6 (one original) has no matching numbers and wins no more cards.
>
> Once all of the originals and copies have been processed, you end up
> with 1 instance of card 1, 2 instances of card 2, 4 instances of card
> 3, 8 instances of card 4, 14 instances of card 5, and 1 instance of
> card 6. In total, this example pile of scratchcards causes you to
> ultimately have 30 scratchcards!
>
> Process all of the original and copied scratchcards until no more
> scratchcards are won. Including the original set of scratchcards, how
> many total scratchcards do you end up with?

See what I mean? That's a mouthful!

```
# (omitted: boilerplate header and shared nums_to_lines function from part 1)

solve_2023_day4_part2() {
  local counts index left right count nextIndex sum

  # Storage to track the card counts at indexes.
  counts=()
  index=0

  sum=0
  # Read the left and right parts, delimited by '|' 
  while IFS='|' read left right; do
    # Initialize or increment counter.
    if [[ ${counts[$index]+x} ]]; then
      ((++counts[index]))
    else
      ((counts[index] = 1))
    fi

    # Strip the "Card N:" prefix from left.
    left=${left#*: }

    # Count the exact matches of numbers in the right among in the left.
    # Warning: running a program (grep) in a loop is inefficient.
    # When this becomes a performance bottleneck, this is easy enough
    # to implement in pure Bash.
    count=$(grep -xFcf <(nums_to_lines "$right") <(nums_to_lines "$left")) || true
    ((sum += counts[index]))

    # Update the count of subsequent cards.
    # Warning: there may be wasted storage and CPU here for indexes beyond
    # the number of cards. Ignoring that for now until it becomes a problem.
    for ((nextIndex = index + 1; nextIndex < index + 1 + count; ++nextIndex)); do
      if [[ ${counts[$nextIndex]+x} ]]; then
        ((counts[nextIndex] += counts[index]))
      else
        ((counts[nextIndex] = counts[index]))
      fi
    done

    ((++index))
  done

  echo "$sum"
}

solve_2023_day4_part2
```

#### Review request

I do realize this is a bit whimsical, and Bash is not a great choice to solve algorithmic puzzles. The solver is intended as a one-off, and not for reuse.

Do you see any patterns here that you would replace with better patterns?

Do you see a simpler way to solve any part of the puzzle with Bash and common shell tools?

What would you do differently?

#### The Devil's advocate

I'll be the first to say that the `grep` sticks out like a sore thumb. It's a major performance hit with multiple subprocesses for each line of input, for something that can be easily written in native Bash. I didn't bother to optimize that part because:

1. This is fast enough for its purpose, at less than 1 second on my laptop.
2. I have no plans for future extensions of this script.
3. I thought this is a nice demonstration of things you can do with `grep`, and a more interesting solution than my Bash implementation would be.

Comment: https://github.com/choroba/aoc23/commit/451019c0c6465818bd6bef816a7df8e0f69eab08

Answer (score 3):

## one word per line

In `nums_to_lines`, these six lines follow a very clear pattern.
But it seems a bit long.
I tend to use `echo ${nums} | fmt -w1`
when numpy's `nums.T` transpose operator is not available.

I *do* like the conservative `set`.

---

## matching

```
grep -xFcf  <(nums_to_lines "$right")  < /tmp/winning-numbers.txt
```

For clarity, maybe start with `grep -c`? The `-x` and `-F` are
closely related to each other, and related to the following `-f`,
essentially producing this for that first example card:

```
grep -c '^(83|86|6|31|17|9|48|53)$'  < /tmp/winning-numbers.txt
```

There are many ways to skin this cat.
I thought for sure I would see `sort -n` invocations,
followed by `comm -12`, as the most natural way
to compute set intersection in a bash pipeline.

---

## no fork

```
    # Strip the "Card N:" prefix from left.
    left=${left#*: }
```

Thank you very much for that comment.
It is not merely helpful; it is essential.
Else I would have no idea what that expression had computed.
(Recommend you elide the final SPACE after the `:` colon.)

The trouble with bash
[line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem#1980s)
[noise](https://linux.die.net/man/1/perlop)
is that it's so difficult to consult the bash docs
to find what an expression means.
Grep reports thirty matches for `#` hash,
twice that for `*` star,
and twice again for `:` colon.
We have accreted one feature after another
for more than half a century, and at some
point the edifice sags under its own weight.

IMHO, `echo $left | sed 's/^Card [0-9]*: //'`
would more clearly express Author's Intent,
without need of a comment.
But maybe that just comes from using regexes
so often in lots of contexts, some of them
involving a bash command line.

```
    # Compute power of 2 and add to sum.
    ((sum += 1 << (count - 1)))
```

Again, I thank you for the helpful comment.
Not quite as essential, but still helpful.

And I'm surprised that the swiss army knife named bash
lacks exponentiation. Guess we didn't like the
[bc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc)
`^` power operator?

It would cost a fork().
And would save on clarity.

---

## default dict

I confess I'm a bit
[spoiled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
by python's standard library.
We see this pattern pop up in any language that offers a HashMap,
which is to say,
in every language.

```
      if [[ ${counts[$nextIndex]+x} ]]; then
        ((counts[nextIndex] += counts[index]))
      else
        ((counts[nextIndex] = counts[index]))
      fi
```

This is perfectly lovely as-is.

I ask one and all: Is there some bash idiom for
expressing this more compactly?
(Specifically, for incrementing a possibly non-existent entry
as though it already held a `0`.)

Comment: I don't think `sort -n` + `comm -12` is "the most natural way" to compute set intersection in a bash pipeline. It's *a* way. As for navigating `man bash`, yes it helps to know the proper terms for some constructs, in this example "Parameter Expansion". Other than that, I find it fantastic docs, almost everything is there. As for default dict, I learned a neat trick from Choroba, see my answer.

Comment: Ooohhh, I like it. I use e.g. `first_param=${1:-default_value}` all the time, but it hadn't occurred to me to use it in this context. Nice. //  As far as "natural" goes, I shy away from quadratic solutions if I can get O(N log N) plus [2-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm) to accomplish the same task. Sometimes an RDBMS is doing the heavy lifting for that, but not always. It's just how I think about the data flow. And then I look for a matching tool.

Answer (score 3):

Got a tip from [@choroba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/17266/choroba)'s [alternative solution](https://github.com/choroba/aoc23/commit/451019c0c6465818bd6bef816a7df8e0f69eab08).

To conditionally initialize or update an entry in a map, instead of:

> ```
> if [[ ${counts[$nextIndex]+x} ]]; then
>   ((counts[nextIndex] += counts[index]))
> else
>   ((counts[nextIndex] = counts[index]))
> fi
> ```

A simpler idiom is using *Default Values* syntax `${parameter:-word}` of *Parameter Expansion*:

```
((counts[$nextIndex] = ${counts[$nextIndex]:-0} + counts[index]))
```

This is applicable at two places in the solution for Part 2, making the code simpler and more compact.

This is compatible with `set -u` (no errors raised for referencing an undefined value).